# How to assign/access variables in if statements on the same level

Tags: java

So, i need to access the variables I assigned in the if statements in the last if statement. I am a beginner in Java and any help is appreciated :)

Here is my compilation error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
The local variable a may not have been initialized
The local variable b may not have been initialized
The local variable c may not have been initialized
The local variable d may not have been initialized
The local variable e may not have been initialized
```

And here is my code. I need to assign a certain variable based on how many iterations have passed, and access the variables after they have been assigned on the last iteration.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String a;
    String b;
    String c;
    String d;
    String e;
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

for( int loop = 1; loop <= 6; loop++ ){
    if(loop == 1){
        System.out.println("Please input a grade.");
        a = s.nextLine();
        System.out.println("You said,"+a);
        continue;
        }
    if(loop == 2){
        System.out.println("Please input a grade.");;
        b = s.nextLine();
        System.out.println("You said,"+b);
        continue;
    }
    if(loop == 3){
        System.out.println("Please input a grade.");
        c = s.nextLine();
        System.out.println("You said," +c);
        continue;
    }
    if(loop == 4){
        System.out.println("Please input a grade.");
        d = s.nextLine();
        System.out.println("You said," +d);
        continue;
    }
    if(loop == 5){
        System.out.println("Please input a grade.");
        e = s.nextLine();
        System.out.println("You said," +e);
        continue;
    }
    if(loop == 6){
        System.out.println("Grade 1."+a);
        System.out.println("Grade 1."+b);
        System.out.println("Grade 1."+c);
        System.out.println("Grade 1."+d);
        System.out.println("Grade 1."+e);
    }


    }
}
```

Comment: `String a = "";` should do the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are declaring and then trying to access the String. You must initialize them first if you you're going to use the variables. You declare them by doing this:

```
String a;
```

You need to also initialize them like this:

```
String a = "";
```

Initialize them before you try to access them or Java's compiler will not be happy!

Answer (score 3):

Actually, the correct thing to do in this case would be *removing the loop and the if statements*. They are superfluous. There is no need to do a loop if you are not running any of the operations inside it more than once:

```
String a;
String b;
String c;
String d;
String e;

System.out.println("Please input a grade.");
a = s.nextLine();
System.out.println("You said,"+a);

System.out.println("Please input a grade.");;
b = s.nextLine();
System.out.println("You said,"+b);

System.out.println("Please input a grade.");
c = s.nextLine();
System.out.println("You said," +c);

System.out.println("Please input a grade.");
d = s.nextLine();
System.out.println("You said," +d);

System.out.println("Please input a grade.");
e = s.nextLine();
System.out.println("You said," +e);

System.out.println("Grade 1."+a);
System.out.println("Grade 1."+b);
System.out.println("Grade 1."+c);
System.out.println("Grade 1."+d);
System.out.println("Grade 1."+e);
```

This will give you *exactly* the same flow of control, but now the compiler can see that all the variables had to have been initialized.

Loops are for running some part of the program logic repeatedly with small differences. In fact, if you had used an array instead of your variables, it would make sense to have a loop:

```
String[] grades = new String[6];

for ( int loop = 0; loop < 6; loop++ ) {

    System.out.println("Please input a grade.");
    grades[loop] = s.nextLine();
    System.out.println("You said," + grades[loop]);

}

for ( int loop = 0; loop < 6; loop++ ) {
    System.out.println( "Grade " + ( loop + 1 ) + ". " + grades[loop] );
}
```

So instead of writing all of those lines six times, we wrote them just once, with change that depends on the loop variable. This is what loops were made for.

Comment: Oh! Thats very useful :) I knew i could make it shorter but i hadn't gotten to fully understand arrays yet. (I'm in 10th grade)

Answer (score 2):

Just do this when you create your Strings:

```
String a = "";
String b = "";
String c = "";
String d = "";
String e = "";
```

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help out. @Miguel J does a good job of explaining why this works. Be sure to accept an answer!